# Update selector after flexslider has initialized

Tags: flexslider

I'm trying to use Flexslider as a carousel for a filterable list of items. If i use the selector ".slider > .visible", Flexslider loads correctly when the page loads. However, if click on the filter controls, the elements that have the class .visible change, but flexslider doesn't display the newly filtered items and instead rotates through blank items.

Is there a way to force Flexslider to refresh the elements after it has been initialized?